# Invalid Argument in Open method for web scraping

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape some data from the ancestry, I have a .net background but thought i'd try a bit of python for a project.
I'm falling at the first step, Firstly i am trying to open this page and then just print out the rows.

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw_html = open('https://www.ancestry.co.uk/search/collections/britisharmyservice/? 
birth=_merthyr+tydfil-wales-united+kingdom_1651442').read()
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
for p in html.select('tblrow record'):
    print(p)
```

I am getting an illegal argument on open.

Comment: `open` is used for files, not webpages. You probably meant to use `requests.get`.

Comment: Ah, the tutorial I was following has it wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is used to:

> Open [a] file and return a corresponding file object.

As such, you cannot use it for downloading the HTML contents of a webpage. You probably meant to use [`requests.get`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.get) as follows:

```
raw_html = get('https://www.ancestry.co.uk/search/collections/britisharmyservice/? 
birth=_merthyr+tydfil-wales-united+kingdom_1651442').text
# .text gets the raw text of the response 
# (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text)
```

Here are a few recommendation to improve your code as well:

1. `requests.get` provides many useful parameters, one of them being `params`, which allows you to provide the URL parameters in the form of a Python dictionary.
2. If you need to verify whether the request was successful before accessing its text, then just check if the returned `response.status_code == requests.codes.ok`. This only covers status code 200, but if you need more codes, then `response.raise_for_status` should be helpful.